# Webkit does not work with GoDaddy SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, certificate, godaddy

Web purchased an ssl certificate from GoDaddy and installed it correctly.  But, on any webkit browser it says that the site is not trusted.  Does anyone have any idea why webkit would not like GoDaddy certificates?

Here are the site details:

[alt text http://www.puc.edu/__data/assets/image/0012/62022/Screen-shot-2010-01-05-at-12.01.07-PM.png](http://www.puc.edu/__data/assets/image/0012/62022/Screen-shot-2010-01-05-at-12.01.07-PM.png)

Could it be an older version of Apache or openssl?  Would this effect the validity of the certificate?

Contacting GoDaddy has been no help, they know nothing more than what they read out of their support manuals.

Comment: puc.edu. comes up just fine for me in Chrome (WinXP)

Comment: Did you try https://www.puc.edu?  I have been testing this on a Mac so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more likely to be an issue at the client end: do your webkit-based clients have the latest trusted root certificates installed?  Also, have you installed GoDaddy's intermediate and root certificates on your webserver?

Comment: Yes, we have it installed correctly.

Comment: On the clients as well?  It loads just fine in Chromium/Vista.

Answer (score 0):

The SSL checker shows that the server isn't sending out any Intermediate certificates. This isn't a problem on most browsers because they trust the GoDaddy issuing certificate by default. To get it to work for WebKit browsers you just need to put the following in a file called intermediates.crt:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Then make sure you have this line (with the actual path to the certificate) in your Apache config file next to SSLCertificateFile and SSLCertificateKeyFile:

```
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/crt/intermediates.crt
```

Once that is install, you should see those certificates being given out by the server when checking with the [SSL Checker](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html).